# Vtiger select query

Tags: smarty, crm, vtiger

I'm copying a vtiger query in a similar way but there is one change that the query given first having only one output so there is kept 0 in 2nd argument,
but in my customized query there are multiple outputs so what should I kept instead of 0
both are given as below:

1. original query

`$is_recurring_event_query = $adb->pquery('SELECT recurring_group_id from vtiger_activity where activityid=?',array($id));`

`$is_recurring_event = $adb->query_result($is_recurring_event_query,0,'recurring_group_id');`

1. copying it to use at different way

`$is_recurring_event_activity_query = $adb->pquery('SELECT activityid from vtiger_activity where recurring_group_id='.$is_recurring_event);`

`$is_recurring_event_activity = $adb->query_result ($is_recurring_event_activity_query,0,'activityid');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put variable and have to use for loop for your query to execute and get multiple values.

Suppose your query is like this

```
$result = $adb->pquery ('SELECT * from vtiger_activity where id='.$recordId);
$noofrow = $adb->num_rows($result );
for($i=0; $i<$noofrow ; $i++) {
            $Data['activityid']=$adb->query_result($result,$i,'activityid');
            $Data['activityname']=$adb->query_result($result,$i,'activityname');
}
```

Here in $Data you will get an array of the values.